# Can you use Gravatar?

Tags: support, gravatar

I have Gravatar, but I want to have it as my user icon. Anyway, I can do that?

My Gravatar is [email removed], and I also would like to see if that we had Gravatar, would it remove any stickers? Would we have to refresh our logo every time we made a new Gravatar?

I could try copying and pasting the image every time, but that'd be a hassle.

Any way this could get done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your main site profile click the "Edit profile and settings" tab and then click "Change picture".  Select "gravatar".

[image]

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the help!